# Highstock - Soft Min and Max is not working

Tags: highcharts

I am working on `Highstock` chart and I want to apply `SoftMin` and `SoftMax` to the xAxis. But it is not working.

Here is the code which I try to set SoftMin and Max:

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({
    softMax: (new Date(2022, 11, 01)).getTime(),
  softMin: (new Date(2017, 11, 01)).getTime()
 }, true);

chart.xAxis[1].update({
    softMax: (new Date(2022, 11, 01)).getTime(),
  softMin: (new Date(2017, 11, 01)).getTime()
}, true);
```

[JSFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lok76pd/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because of the `xAxis.ordinal` which is set to `true` by default in Highstock. Disable it and it will work as expected.

Code:

```
xAxis: {
  ordinal: false
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/25yncsv0/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal